# Combobox first lookup extremely slow, successive better

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

I have a combox that is bound to a store containing 7.5k records. This combobox is being used in an `Ext.grid.Gridpanel` through the cell editing plugin.

What I am noticing is that for the first time a user utilizes the combobox the first query sent to the store is taking near 10-15 seconds. However, after this every query is normal taking less then 1 second.

I was searching around the web and ran across [this](https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?229990-How-to-improve-performance-of-a-Combobox-with-a-large-store-with-local-queryMode) post. I tried the suggestions, but didn't notice any performance increase.

I am relatively new to ExtJS so any pointers would be appreciated.

**Technical Details**

```
//Model
Ext.define('Product',{
   extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
   fields: [{
     name: 'name', type:'string'
   },{
     name: 'make', type:'string'
   },{
     name: 'model', type: 'string'
  }]
}); 

// Store
Ext.define('MyApp.store.productStore',{
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    model: 'Product'  
});



//Cell configuration
{
            text: 'Proposed Product', 
            flex: 3,
            dataIndex: 'name',
            menuDisabled: true,
            fixed : false,
            sortable: false,
            hideable: false,
            menuDisabled: true,
            align: 'center',
            editor:
            {
                xtype: 'combobox',
                hideTrigger: true,
                forceSelection:true, // disallow users from leaving invalid text
                emptyText: 'Search for Product',
                queryMode: 'local',
                displayField: 'name',
                valueField: 'name',
                activeFilter: true, 
                minChars: 3,
                listConfig:{
                    minWidth: 350
                }
            }
        }
```

At the time of the cell definition above I do not have that data available to populate the store. It is currently downloading async. Once loaded I am grabbing the combobox and binding the store.

Through observation it looks like the combobox/store is doing some sort of pre-caching. Once this takes place it is smooth sailing. Does anyone know how to reduce its impact or avoid it all together?

Comment: I guess that it has something to do with DOM creation. You could decide to create the DOM before the user gets to click the combo.

Comment: Any idea how I could trigger this functionality before the query? This way the user isn't sitting at a locked up screen.

Comment: did you try on the constructor?

Comment: Hey I am facing the exact same issue with normal combo box (not grid editing combo),  any new information on this issue?

Comment: @Raghu The solution I ended up going with was to bind an empty store. I then listen to the before query and bound a slimmed down store based on what was typed in by the user. This reduced the delay as the store that was bound had fewer results. The reason this happens is once you bind a store it creates all the dom elements at once. so if you have a large store it will choke. good luck.